Vercel deployment changing maxDuration not working, functions config not recognizing my routes
I am trying to deploy my backend to Vercel but increasing the maxDuration to 30 seconds. However, builds does not support modifying a functions maxDuration so I attempted to use the functions config. However, my backend is written in TypeScript using Express with the code compiled in a dist directory. My main route file is called index.js inside an API folder, meaning after compilation that file is in /dist/api/index.js. All my source files themselves are in a src directory so the source location for my index.js file /src/api/index.ts. The rest of the src file structure looks like this:
└───src
    ├───api
    ├───config
    ├───controllers
    ├───db
    │   └───migrations
    │       └───meta
    ├───docs
    │   ├───db
    │   └───routes
    ├───middleware
    │   └───security
    ├───routes
    ├───services
    ├───test
    └───utils

Regardless of what I do, Vercel does not recognize my function and wants it to be in an api directory, which I can't pull off since my compiled files are directed to the dist directory.
My current vercel.json file which functions file but doesn't have a custom maxDuration is:
{
  "version": 2,
  "buildCommand": "npm run build",
  "installCommand": "npm install",
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "dist/api/index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node",
      "config": {
        "includeFiles": ["dist/**"]
      }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "dist/api/index.js"
    }
  ]
}

Snippet of my package.json:
{
    "name": "backend",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "build": "rimraf dist && tsc",
        "ts.check": "tsc --project tsconfig.json",
        "start": " node ./dist/api/index.js",
        "add-build": "git add dist",
        "test": "nyc --reporter=html --reporter=json --reporter=text mocha dist/test --experimental-modules --timeout 10000 --exit",
        "db:generate": "drizzle-kit generate",
        "db:migrate": "drizzle-kit migrate"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "pre-commit": [
        "ts.check",
        "build",
        "add-build"
    ],

A different vercel.json file which I tried:
{
  "version": 2,
  "buildCommand": "npm run build",
  "installCommand": "npm install",
  "outputDirectory": "dist",
  "functions": {
    "api/index.js": {
      "maxDuration": 30,
      "includeFiles": "dist/**"
    }
  }
}

The exact error is:
The pattern "api/index.js" defined in `functions` doesn't match any Serverless Functions inside the `api` directory.
